# What is the best approach to make 3 column fixed width cross browser compatible, accessible, semantically correct layout?

Tags: css, xhtml, web-standards

What is the best approach to  make 3 column fixed width cross browser compatible, accessible, semantically correct layout ?

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            This is the Header
        </div>
        <div id="top-nav">
            Top Navigation
        </div>
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            Left Column
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            content column
        </div>
        <div id="rightcolumn">
            Right Column
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            This is the Footer
        </div>
    </div>




#wrapper {width:970px;margin:0 auto }
 #header {height:100px  }
 #top-nav {height:30px}
 #leftcolumn {  }
 #content {  }
 #rightcolumn {  }
 #footer {height:100px}
```

With this XHTML code what css should be written to make this 3 col layout.

- cross browser compatible including
  IE6 (without CSS hack or extra
  conditional css for IE)
- Width in Px
- Centered
- Font-sizing in em
- Number of column can be extended or
  removed 1-4,5 etc
- SEO Enabled

Comment: Normally I'm not anal, but this question has been asked thousands of times and you should be able to google up a hundred or so solutions. Do you have a specific markup structure you're catering it to, such as content before nav?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533607/css-three-column-layout-problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042101/cross-browser-three-column-layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867667/is-there-a-simple-3-column-pure-css-layout

Comment: You could at least point out that the image is from http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, this is pretty darn easy with floats and faux columns.

Why do you have so many containers around the columns? You only need one. To clear the floats, do

```
#container {
    width:960px; /* or 100%, or whatever. It needs to be set for it to work in IE tho */
    overflow:auto; /* hidden works too */
    background:url(./img/faux-columns.gif) repeat-y; /* google faux columns for A List Apart article */
}
```

and for the columns themselves

```
#col1 { width:520px; float:left; margin-right:20px; }
#col2 { width:200px; float:left; margin-right:20px; }
#col3 { width:200px; float:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery + its layout plug-in. Keep your full head of hair.